# How to group data by labels and return a list of calculated values?

Tags: python, list, statistics

Let us suppose that I have two lists with the SAME number of elements. The first contains just floating point numbers, the second one contains string labels. For example:

```
[1.98, 5.56, 4.34, 9.35, 6.23, 2.54, 8.31, 7.49]
[ "ABC", "LMN", "XYZ", "ABC", "ABC", "XYZ", "XYZ", "LMN"]
```

Let us suppose that I have also a list of ordered unique labels:

```
["ABC", "LMN", "XYZ"]
```

I want to write the most efficient Python code that:

1. group values by labels
2. apply a specific function to those values (eg. sum, mean, stdev)
3. returns a list of calculated values **in the same order** of label list.

For example, if the function is sum, I expect a list of three values:

```
[sum(1.98, 9.35, 6.23), sum(5.56, 7.49), sum(4.34, 2.54, 8.31)]
```

If the function is mean, I expect a list of three values:

```
[mean(1.98, 9.35, 6.23), mean(5.56, 7.49), mean(4.34, 2.54, 8.31)]
```

Any hint?

Comment: in many cases using a `dict` is better than 2 relational lists. in case the order matters, you can use [ordered dict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First reshape your data using a dictionary to group the values per key. Since python 3.7 dictionary keys are guaranteed to be in their order of insertion.

```
values = [1.98, 5.56, 4.34, 9.35, 6.23, 2.54, 8.31, 7.49]
keys = ["ABC", "LMN", "XYZ", "ABC", "ABC", "XYZ", "XYZ", "LMN"]

order = ["ABC", "LMN", "XYZ"]

out = {k:[] for k in order}

for key, value in zip(keys, values):
    out[key].append(value)
```

output:

```
>>> out
{'ABC': [1.98, 9.35, 6.23], 'LMN': [5.56, 7.49], 'XYZ': [4.34, 2.54, 8.31]}
```

Then apply any transform you want

```
# sum
[round(sum(v),2) for v in out.values()]
#[17.56, 13.05, 15.19]

# mean
from statistics import mean
[round(mean(v),2) for v in out.values()]
# [5.85, 6.53, 5.06]
```

###### order of the initial keys

if you want, you can also keep the order of the keys in your list of keys, without needing an explicit list of ordered keys:

```
from collections import defaultdict

values = [1.98, 5.56, 4.34, 9.35, 6.23, 2.54, 8.31, 7.49]
keys = ["ABC", "LMN", "XYZ", "ABC", "ABC", "XYZ", "XYZ", "LMN"]

out = defaultdict(list)
for key, value in zip(keys, values):
    out[key].append(value)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
values = [1.98, 5.56, 4.34, 9.35, 6.23, 2.54, 8.31, 7.49]
keys = ["ABC", "LMN", "XYZ", "ABC", "ABC", "XYZ", "XYZ", "LMN"]

order = ["ABC", "LMN", "XYZ"]

out = {k:[] for k in order}

for key, value in zip(keys, values):
    out[key].append(value)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

```
data = [1.98, 5.56, 4.34, 9.35, 6.23, 2.54, 8.31, 7.49]
keys = [ "ABC", "LMN", "XYZ", "ABC", "ABC", "XYZ", "XYZ", "LMN"]
labels = ["ABC", "LMN", "XYZ"]
func = max
result = [func([data[ind] for ind in [i for i, x in enumerate(keys) if x == label]]) for label in labels]
print(result)
```

You can change your function as you want.
My code concatenate loops in one line.

Answer (score 1):

This is a common use case when one gets a list of labels for a list/array of values from some model prediction (for instance when using the function `predict` in sklearn) and one wants see for each distinct label the values that get assigned that label according to the model.

```
values = [ 1.98,   5.56,  4.34,  9.35,  6.23,  2.54,  8.31, 7.49 ]
labels = [ "ABC", "LMN", "XYZ", "ABC", "ABC", "XYZ", "XYZ", "LMN"]
```

**Group values by label**

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(list)
for k,v in zip(labels, values):
    d[k].append(v)

d
# defaultdict(list,
#             {'ABC': [1.98, 9.35, 6.23],
#              'LMN': [5.56, 7.49],
#              'XYZ': [4.34, 2.54, 8.31]})
```

Show grouped values by sorted labels

```
for label in sorted(d):
    print('{} {}'.format(label, d[label]))
# ABC [1.98, 9.35, 6.23]
# LMN [5.56, 7.49]
# XYZ [4.34, 2.54, 8.31]
```

**Sum values by label**

```
for label in d:
    print('{} {:.4f}'.format(label, sum(d[label])))
# ABC 17.5600
# LMN 13.0500
# XYZ 15.1900
```

**Compute mean value by label**

```
d_avg = {k: sum(d[k])/len(d[k]) for k in d}
for label in d_avg:
    print('{} {:.4f}'.format(label, d_avg[label]))
# ABC 5.8533
# LMN 6.5250
# XYZ 5.0633
```